# Check if UITableViewCell is completely visible for automatic playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm building a social media app that has a feed of posts. It's required to start playback of assigned track to a post when a post is fully visible on a screen. This is a lay out I have now.

[image: Current layout, 2 items visible]

This is a piece of code I figured out, but it only works with a very first post in a timeline.

```js
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    let visibleCell = tableView.visibleCells.first as! HomeControllerTableViewCell
    
    
    let firstCellVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first
  
    
    if tableView.bounds.contains(tableView.rectForRow(at: firstCellVisibleIndexPath!)){
      let fullyVisibleCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: firstCellVisibleIndexPath!) as! HomeControllerTableViewCell
      
      print(fullyVisibleCell.authorNameLabel.text)
      
    }
    
  }
```

Please help me figure out how to determine what cell is fully visible.

Comment: You are testing only on the first one: `tableView.visibleCells.first`. Instead, let allvisibleCells = `tableView.visibleCells`, and do a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I ended in determining what cell is fully visible regarding my layout

```js
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    

    
    for item in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!{
      if tableView.bounds.contains(tableView.rectForRow(at: item)){
        let fullyVisibleCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: item) as! HomeControllerTableViewCell
        
       
 
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let location = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: tablePostView)
    guard let indexPath = tablePostView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
        print("could not specify an indexpath")
        return
    }

    print("will begin dragging at row \(indexPath.row)")
    let cellRect = tablePostView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let completelyVisible = tablePostView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
    print(completelyVisible)}
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer! Rather than just submitting only a solution in code, try to provide context. Why was OPs solution not working? Why does yours work? Is there a concept that OP needs to understand?